# Section receiving cell values of other section

Tags: iphone

I am trying to get the first five cards in one section and other five in next section of table view . Actually I have done parsing and unable to get proper cell values. The thing I am getting is combined values for example : in `section = birthday` cell values are `card1`, `card2` and again `card1`, `card 2` of `new year section`, and in other section same thing is repeating. What should I do to make grouped i.e `card1`, card 2 in birthday section and `card1`, `card2`  should be in new year section. Here is my code:

```cc
 (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
    NSLog(@"section in rv");
}

 (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [appDelegate.books count];
        NSLog(@".....appDelegate.books count");
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"cell for index path");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
      {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
              }
    Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"text for cell...");
    cell.text = aBook.Subcatname;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
    [appDelegate release];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at dks1725's response to set up the correct number of rows per section.

Also, and more directly in response to your question, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for each table row you are always returning a cell with the same content, regardless of what section the cell is in.  That's why you are getting the same content ('card1', 'card2' and so on) appearing in each section.

Keep in mind that the `indexPath` you are receiving in this method has two components: `indexPath.row`and `indexPath.section`.  You are ignoring the second of these, and so, for every section, you always return the same cell for a each row.

You will need to modify `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so that a piece of it will look something like the following:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    //Retrieve the content you want for each row in section 0
    //It will look something like this, but will be different depending on where you stored your content

    Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = birthdayBook.Subcatname;
}
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    //Retrieve the content you want for each row in section 1
    //It will look something like this, but will be different depending on where you stored your content

    Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 5];
    cell.text = newyearsBook.Subcatname;
}
...
```

The above is edited as per your comments.
Given your model, you could also do it in fewer lines, as follows:

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionName = nil;
    switch(section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = [NSString stringWithString:@"birthday"];
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = [NSString stringWithString:@"new year"];
    }
    return sectionName;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       NSInteger count; 
       if(section == 0) 
       { count=5; } 
       else if(section == 1)
       { count=5; }
       return count;
   }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"cell for index path");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
      {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
         }
    NSLog(@"text for cell...");
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {       
      Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.text = aBook.Subcatname;
           }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
      Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5*indexPath.section];
       cell.text = aBook.Subcatname;
        }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
    [appDelegate release]; 

      }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    if(bdvController == nil)
        bdvController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    NSLog(@"pushing to bdv controller");
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {       
        Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        bdvController.aBook = aBook;
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5*indexPath.section];
    bdvController.aBook = aBook;
    }
        NSLog(@"push to view descrip, id, pic url");
    //bdvController.aBook = aBook;
    NSLog(@"loop");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have only one array books and want to show 1st 5 elements of arrays in one section and next 5 elements in 2nd section

Comment: Then, for section 0, you may leave the code as you have it: 'Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]'

Comment: And, for section 2: 'Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 5]'

Comment: For -tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: just always return 5, since both sections have 5 rows.

Comment: @salo: i have tried but same repeating value in the section = 1. i am editing the above code to show you what i am doing!!

Comment: I edited the response to incorporate the notes in the comments.  It should be easier to read now.

Comment: if(indexPath.section == 0)
 {  
   Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.text = aBook.Subcatname;
   
   }
 else if(indexPath.section == 1)
 {
   Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 5 * indexPath.section];
    cell.text = aBook.Subcatname;
     
     }

Comment: The code in your comment looks good, unless there's a minor syntax error.  See the new edit.  You can copy the whole method as is.  If it still doesn't work you might check the array to see that it has the correct information.

Comment: @salo: Its working :) .. i dnt know what i have done!! it worked so immediately. i am updating the code .... thanks for the help!! r

Comment: Glad you got it to work!  As you get more comfortable with the language, you may want to give some consideration to writing simpler code, that is, writing the same thing in fewer lines.  The more lines of code you have, the greater likelihood of error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set number of rows for each section something like below..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if(indexPath.section==0)
       //return no of rows for section 0
    else
      //return no of rows for section 1
}
```

Comment: But it is showing again same values in 2nd section repeating values not showing the next values...I hav used <pre> if(section==0)
  return 5;
 else
  return 5;
</pre>

Comment: can u plz give data of you array?i mean what data are there in your array and what you want to display exactly\

Comment: in my array its multiple attributes like catagory name , subcatagory name , url etc etc. i am showing only subcatagory name in my cell.